# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/anim/dom/SVGDOMImplementation error

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop, batik

I included below code in xsl-fo document:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">
<g style="fill:red; stroke:#000000">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15"/>
<rect x="5" y="5" width="15" height="15"/>
</g>
</svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

i need to create a pdf ,I am using fop 1.0,batik-all-1.8pre-r1084380.

While running the xsl fo code ,i got the following error.

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/anim/dom/SVGDOMImplementation
```

Kindly help.

Comment: There seems to be some Batik classes missing on the class path. Have you tried switching to the latest official production version (you seem to be using a custom-built pre-release)?

Comment: @haraldK can u point me to exact batik 1.8.jar version,i could download batik -all 1.8.jar

Comment: Did you try the official [Apache Batik download page](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/download.html)? I'm not so concerned about the `-all` part, but the `pre-r...` part sounds like a pre-release.

Comment: @haraldK I have solved the problem.thanks though